# Как указать путь к ssl сертефикату в Git [Windows]

Tags: git, github, git-push

Переустанавливал *git* и похоже настройки криво встали, теперь при `Git PUSH` выдает вот такое сообщение

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/RenatGafarov/remindme.server.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
>     CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>     CApath: none

Как указать путь к этим библиотекам?(*Git* установлен в *"C:/Git"*)

Comment: Решил проблему просто скопировав сертификаты из "C:/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/" в "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/", но хотелось бы решить проблему правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из комментария:

---

Решил проблему просто скопировав сертификаты из "C:/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/" в "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/".